# The conditions for a shift in a loop momentum to be allowed

Tags: quantum-field-theory, renormalization, feynman-diagrams, regularization, dimensional-regularization

When we evaluate the Feynman diagram containing a loop, we commonly use the identity:
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{A_{1}^{m_{1}} A_{2}^{m_{2}} \cdots A_{n}^{m_{n}}}=
\int_{0}^{1} d x_{1} \cdots d x_{n} \delta\left(\sum x_{i}-1\right) \frac{\prod x_{i}^{m_{i}-1}}{\left[\sum x_{i} A_{i}\right]^{\Sigma m_{i}}} \frac{\Gamma\left(m_{1}+\cdots+m_{n}\right)}{\Gamma\left(m_{1}\right) \cdots \Gamma\left(m_{n}\right)}
\end{align}
to combine denominators of propagators, and make shifts in the loop momentum so that the denominator has a form:
\begin{align}
\left[\ell^{2}-\Delta\right]^{m}
\end{align}
where $\ell$ is the loop momentum, and $\Delta$ doesn't depend on $\ell$.

However, I'm not sure if this procedure is always valid. Would someone know the conditions for shifts to be allowed or give me an example we cannot make the shifts?

Comment: As far as dubious manipulations go in QFT, this is pretty tame.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we use [dimensional regularization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimensional_regularization), if $x$ denotes the [Feynman parameters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feynman_parametrization), and if the denominator $$\ell^2+ 2a(x)\cdot \ell+ b(x)=\ell^{\prime 2}-\Delta(x)$$ is a quadratic expression in the loop-momentum $\ell^{\mu}$, then clearly the shift of integration variable is
$$ \ell^{\prime \mu}~=~\ell^{\mu}+a^{\mu}(x), \qquad \Delta(x)~=~a(x)^2-b(x).$$
This should in principle always work, but be aware that it may shift the integration contour, cf. e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/689539/2451) Phys.SE post.

Answer (score 1):

As long as the integral is defined, we have
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty dx f(x) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty dx f(x+a) , \qquad a \in {\mathbb R}$$
In dimensional regularization, the loop integrals are all $UV$ finite (for sufficiently large $d$) so the shift in the loop momentum is ALWAYS ok to do.