# Branch cut of a one-loop bubble diagram after cutting a single propagator

Tags: quantum-field-theory, feynman-diagrams, integration, unitarity, analyticity

I am trying to understand Cutkosky cutting rules and generalized unitarity. Consider the article https://arxiv.org/abs/0808.1446 by Arkani-Hamed, Cachazo & Kaplan. In chapter 5.1 equation 133, the amplitude of a one-loop bubble diagram looks like

\begin{equation}
    I(P^2) = \int d^4\ell \frac{1}{(\ell^2+i\epsilon)((\ell-P)^2+i\epsilon)},\tag{133}
\end{equation}

which is logarithmically divergent. By cutting both the 2 propagators we obtain the discontinuity of the amplitude:
\begin{equation}
    \Delta I(P^2) = \int d^4\ell \delta^+(\ell^2)\delta^+((\ell-P)^2).\tag{134}
\end{equation}

I would like to show that by cutting the first propagator I obtain a function with a branch cut and then cutting the second propagator I get the actual discontinuity.
My problem is that I am unable to obtain the function with the branch cut after only one cut, in particular if some regularization is introduced.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems OP wants to explicitly calculate the 0-cut, 1-cut
and 2-cut amplitudes for the 1-loop 2-point function,
presumably to verify the
[Cutkosky cutting rules](https://www.google.com/search?as_q=cutkosky+cutting+rules),
cf. Refs. 2-3. Here we generalize to $d$ spacetime dimensions for a massive scalar.

I) The 0-cut 1-loop 2-point amplitude in Minkowski$^1$
signature with real momentum $p^{\mu}\in \mathbb{R}^d$ is$^2$

$$\begin{align}
{\cal M}_0(p)&\cr
~:=~&\frac{1}{i}\int\!\frac{d^d k^{\bullet}}{(2\pi)^d}
\frac{1}{\left(k^2+m^2-i\epsilon \right)
\left((p\!-\!k)^2+m^2-i\epsilon \right)}  \cr 
~\stackrel{(14.9)}{=}~&
\frac{1}{i}\int\!\frac{d^d k^{\bullet}}{(2\pi)^d}\int_0^1\!dx 
\frac{1}{\left[x\left((p\!-\!k)^2+m^2-i\epsilon \right)
+(1\!-\!x)\left(k^2+m^2-i\epsilon \right) \right]^2}   \cr
~=~&\frac{1}{i}\int\!\frac{d^d k^{\bullet}}{(2\pi)^d}
\int_0^1\!dx \frac{1}{\left[k^2-2xk\cdot p+xp^2+m^2-i\epsilon \right]^2}\cr
~\stackrel{\ell^{\mu}=k^{\mu}-x p^{\mu}}{=}&\frac{1}{i}
\int_0^1\!dx\int\!\frac{d^d \ell^{\bullet}}{(2\pi)^d} 
\frac{1}{\left[\ell^2+x(1\!-\!x)p^2+m^2-i\epsilon \right]^2}\cr
~\stackrel{\ell^0=i\ell^0_E}{=}~&
\int_0^1\!dx\int\! \frac{d^d \ell_E}{(2\pi)^d} 
\frac{1}{\left[\ell_E^2+x(1\!-\!x)p^2+m^2-i\epsilon \right]^2}\cr
~\stackrel{(14.27)}{=}~&\frac{\Gamma(2-\frac{d}{2})}{(4\pi)^{d/2}}
\int_{[0,1]}\!dx
\left[x(1-x)p^2+m^2-i\epsilon\right]^{\frac{d}{2}-2}\cr
~\stackrel{2x=1+y}{=}~&\frac{\Gamma(2-\frac{d}{2})}{(4\pi)^{d/2}}
\int_{[-1,1]}\!\frac{dy}{2}~
\left[-(1-y^2)\frac{s}{4}+m^2-i\epsilon\right]^{\frac{d}{2}-2},
\end{align}\tag{A}$$

where the Mandelstam variable

$$ s~\equiv~ -p^2 \tag{B}$$

is the COM energy square. The eq. numbers in eq. (A) refer to Ref. 4.

*Case $s<4m^2$:* No branch cut. The amplitude is real. $\Box$

*Case $s>4m^2$:* There is a branch cut for $y\in[-y_0,y_0]$, where
$$y_0~:=~\sqrt{1-\frac{4m^2}{s}}.\tag{C}$$

The imaginary part is

$$\begin{align}
{\rm Im}{\cal M}_0(p)&\cr
~\stackrel{(A)}{=}~&\frac{\Gamma(2-\frac{d}{2})}{(4\pi)^{d/2}}
{\rm Im}\left(e^{-i\pi(\frac{d}{2}-2)}\right)
\int_{[-y_0,y_0]}\!\frac{dy}{2}~
\left[(1-y^2)\frac{s}{4}-m^2\right]^{\frac{d}{2}-2}\cr
~=~&-\frac{\Gamma(2-\frac{d}{2})}{(4\pi)^{d/2}}
\sin\pi(\frac{d}{2}-2)
\int_{[-y_0,y_0]}\!\frac{dy}{2}~
\left[(y_0^2-y^2)\frac{s}{4}\right]^{\frac{d}{2}-2}\cr
~\stackrel{y^{\prime}=y/y_0}{=}&
-\frac{\Gamma(2-\frac{d}{2})}{(4\pi)^{d/2}}
\sin\frac{\pi d}{2} y_0^{d-3}s^{\frac{d}{2}-2}
\int_{[-1,1]}\!\frac{dy^{\prime}}{2}~
\left[\frac{1-y^{\prime 2}}{4}\right]^{\frac{d}{2}-2}\cr
~\stackrel{2x^{\prime}=1+y^{\prime}}{=}&
-\frac{\Gamma(2-\frac{d}{2})}{(4\pi)^{d/2}\sqrt{s}}
\sin\frac{\pi d}{2}\left(s-4m^2\right)^{\frac{d-3}{2}}
\int_{[0,1]}\!dx^{\prime}~
\left[x^{\prime}(1-x^{\prime})\right]^{\frac{d}{2}-2}\cr
~=~&-\frac{\Gamma(2-\frac{d}{2})}{(4\pi)^{d/2}\sqrt{s}}
\sin\frac{\pi d}{2}\left(s-4m^2\right)^{\frac{d-3}{2}}
B(\frac{d}{2}-1,\frac{d}{2}-1)\cr
~=~&-\frac{\Gamma(2-\frac{d}{2})}{(4\pi)^{d/2}\sqrt{s}}
\sin\frac{\pi d}{2}\left(s-4m^2\right)^{\frac{d-3}{2}}
\frac{\Gamma(\frac{d}{2}-1)^2}{\Gamma(d-2)}\cr
~\stackrel{\text{(AS6.1.17-18)}}{=}&\frac{\pi}{(4\pi)^{d/2}\sqrt{s}}
\left(s-4m^2\right)^{\frac{d-3}{2}}
\frac{\sqrt{4\pi}}{2^{d-2}\Gamma(\frac{d-1}{2})}\cr
~=~&\frac{1}{2^d\pi^{\frac{d-3}{2}}\Gamma(\frac{d-1}{2})\sqrt{s}}
\left(\frac{s}{4}-m^2\right)^{\frac{d-3}{2}}\cr
~\stackrel{(E)}{=}~&
\frac{{\rm Vol}(\mathbb{S}^{d-2})}{8(2\pi)^{d-2}\sqrt{s}}
\left(\frac{s}{4}-m^2\right)^{\frac{d-3}{2}},
\end{align}\tag{D}$$

where we have used

$$
\Gamma(z)\Gamma(1-z)~=~\frac{\pi}{\sin(\pi z)},\tag{AS6.1.17}
$$

$$
\frac{\Gamma(2z)}{\Gamma(z)}
~=~\frac{2^{2z}}{\sqrt{4\pi}} \Gamma(z+\frac{1}{2}).
\tag{AS6.1.18}$$

and the [volume of a $d\!-\!1$ dimensional
sphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volume_of_an_n-ball)

$$ {\rm Vol}(\mathbb{S}^{d-1}) 
~=~2\frac{\pi^{d/2}}{\Gamma(\frac{d}{2})}.\tag{E}$$

II) The double-cut amplitude reads:

$$\begin{align}
i{\cal M}_2(p)&\cr ~:=~&
\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}\!\frac{d^dk^{\bullet}}{(2\pi)^d}
2\pi\delta^+(k^2+m^2)2\pi\delta^+((p-k)^2+m^2)\cr
~\stackrel{(G)}{=}~&
\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}\!\frac{d^dk^{\bullet}}{(2\pi)^{d-2}}
\frac{1}{2\omega_{\vec{k}}}\delta(k^0\!-\!\omega_{\vec{k}})
\frac{1}{2\omega_{\vec{p}-\vec{k}}}
\delta(p^0\!-\!k^0\!-\!\omega_{\vec{p}-\vec{k}})\cr 
~=~&\int_{\mathbb{R}^{d-1}}\!
\frac{d^{d-1}\vec{k}}{(2\pi)^{d-2}}\frac{1}{2\omega_{\vec{k}}}
\frac{1}{2\omega_{\vec{p}-\vec{k}}}
\delta(p^0\!-\!\omega_{\vec{k}}\!-\!\omega_{\vec{p}-\vec{k}}),
\end{align}\tag{F}$$

where the on-shell energy is

$$ \omega_{\vec{k}}~:=~\sqrt{|\vec{k}|^2+m^2}.\tag{G}$$

*Case with timelike $p^2<0$.* To simplify the integral
let's go to the COM frame $p^{\mu}=(p^0,\vec{0})$.
The double-cut amplitude becomes:

$$\begin{align}
i{\cal M}_2&(p^2\!=\!-(p^0)^2)\cr
~\stackrel{(F)}{=}~&
{\rm Vol}(\mathbb{S}^{d-2})
\int_{\mathbb{R}_+}\!\frac{k^{d-2}dk}{(2\pi)^{d-2}}
\frac{1}{(2\omega_{\vec{k}})^2}
\delta(p^0\!-\!2\omega_{\vec{k}})\cr
~=~&{\rm Vol}(\mathbb{S}^{d-2})\Theta(p^0)~
\Theta\left((p^0)^2\!-\!4m^2\right)
\left.\frac{k^{d-2}}{(2\pi)^{d-2}}
\frac{1}{(2\omega_{\vec{k}})^2}\frac{\omega_{\vec{k}}}{2k}
\right|_{k=\sqrt{\frac{(p^0)^2}{4}-m^2}}\cr
~=~&\frac{{\rm Vol}(\mathbb{S}^{d-2})}{4(2\pi)^{d-2}p^0}\Theta(p^0)~
\Theta\left((p^0)^2\!-\!4m^2\right)
\left(\frac{(p^0)^2}{4}-m^2\right)^{\frac{d-3}{2}},
\end{align}\tag{H}$$
which is twice the imaginary part (D) of the amplitude, cf. the Cutkosky cutting rules.

III) The single-cut amplitude reads:

$$\begin{align}
i{\cal M}_1(p)&\cr ~:=~&
\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}\!\frac{d^dk^{\bullet}}{(2\pi)^d}
2\pi\delta^+(k^2+m^2)\frac{1}{(k-p)^2+m^2-i\epsilon}\cr
~\stackrel{(G)}{=}~&\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}\!\frac{d^dk^{\bullet}}{(2\pi)^{d-1}}
\frac{1}{2\omega_{\vec{k}}}\delta(k^0\!-\!\omega_{\vec{k}})
\frac{1}{-(k^0-p^0)^2+(\vec{k}-\vec{p})^2+m^2-i\epsilon}\cr 
~=~&\int_{\mathbb{R}^{d-1}}\!
\frac{d^{d-1}\vec{k}}{(2\pi)^{d-1}}\frac{1}{2\omega_{\vec{k}}}
\frac{1}{-(\omega_{\vec{k}}-p^0)^2+(\vec{k}-\vec{p})^2+m^2-i\epsilon}\cr
~=~&\int_{\mathbb{R}^{d-1}}
\!\frac{d^{d-1}\vec{k}}{(2\pi)^{d-1}}\frac{1}{2\omega_{\vec{k}}}
\frac{1}{2\omega_{\vec{k}}p^0 -2\vec{k}\cdot\vec{p}+p^2-i\epsilon}
.\end{align}\tag{I}$$

*Case with timelike $p^2<0$.* To simplify the integral
let's go to the COM frame $p^{\mu}=(p^0,\vec{0})$.
The single-cut amplitude becomes$^3$:

$$\begin{align}
i{\cal M}_1&(p^2\!=\!-(p^0)^2)\cr
~\stackrel{(I)}{=}~&{\rm Vol}(\mathbb{S}^{d-2})
\int_{\mathbb{R}_+}\!\frac{k^{d-2}dk}{(2\pi)^{d-1}}
\frac{1}{2\omega_{\vec{k}}}
\frac{1}{2\omega_{\vec{k}} p^0 -(p^0)^2-i\epsilon}\cr
~\stackrel{K=k^2}{=}~&
{\rm Vol}(\mathbb{S}^{d-2})
\int_{\mathbb{R}_+}\!\frac{K^{\frac{d-3}{2}}dK}{2(2\pi)^{d-1}}
\frac{1}{2\sqrt{K+m^2}}
\frac{1}{2\sqrt{K+m^2}p^0 -(p^0)^2-i\epsilon}.\end{align}\tag{J}$$

The integrand (J) has a branch cut along the negative real $K$-axis. The denominator has a simple pole at

$$ K~=~\frac{(p^0)^2}{4}-m^2+i\epsilon. \tag{K} $$

Upto this point $p^0\in\mathbb{R}$ was assumed real. We now let

$$p^0~=~|p^0|e^{i\theta/2}~\in~\mathbb{C} \tag{L}$$

be complex, or equivalently

$$(p^0)^2~=~|p^0|^2 e^{i\theta}~\in~\mathbb{C}, \tag{M}$$

in order to study [monodromy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monodromy) $\theta\to \theta+2\pi$. In the process the pole (K) crosses the positive real $K$-axis from below a net number of 1 time if $|p^0|^2>4m^2$ and hence picks up a small clockwise integration circle around the pole, cf. Fig. 7 in Ref. 1. The [residue theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem) yields

$$\begin{align}
&\left[ i{\cal M}_1(p^2\!=\!-(p^0)^2)
\right]^{\theta+2\pi}_{\theta}\cr
~\stackrel{(J)}{=}~&-2\pi i 
\Theta\left(|p^0|^2\!-\!4m^2\right)
{\rm Vol}(\mathbb{S}^{d-2})
\left.\frac{K^{\frac{d-3}{2}}}{2(2\pi)^{d-1}}
\frac{1}{2\sqrt{K+m^2}}\frac{\sqrt{K+m^2}}{p^0}
\right|_{K=\frac{(p^0)^2}{4}-m^2+i\epsilon}\cr
~=~&-i\Theta\left(|p^0|^2\!-\!4m^2\right)\frac{{\rm Vol}(\mathbb{S}^{d-2})}{4(2\pi)^{d-2}p^0} 
\left(\frac{(p^0)^2}{4}-m^2+i\epsilon\right)^{\frac{d-3}{2}},
\end{align}\tag{N}$$

which agrees with the double-cut amplitude (H).

References:

1. N. Arkani-Hamed, F. Cachazo & J. Kaplan, *What is the Simplest QFT?,*
   [arXiv:0808.1446](https://arxiv.org/abs/0808.1446); eqs. (133)-(134).
2. M.D. Schwartz, [*QFT & the standard model*](https://schwartzqft.fas.harvard.edu/),
   2014; Subsection 24.1.2.
3. M. Le Bellac, *Quantum & Statistical FT,* 1991; Section 10.4.
4. M. Srednicki, *QFT, 2007;* chapter 14. A prepublication draft PDF file is
   available [here](http://web.physics.ucsb.edu/%7Emark/qft.html).

---

$^1$ We have changed the Minkowski sign convention $(+,-,\ldots,-)$
in Ref. 1 to $(-,+,\ldots,+)$. We work in units where $c=1=\hbar$.

$^2$ To avoid IR singularities when mass $m>0$ ($m=0$), let the spacetime dimension $d>1$ ($d>2$), respectively. The UV
[superficial degree of divergence](https://www.google.com/search?as_q=superficial+degree+divergence)
(SDOD) of the 0-cut integral is $D=d-4$,
while the the 1-cut integral has SDOD $D=d-3$.
Altogether let's assume $2<d<3$.
Other $d$ are obtained via analytical continuation.

$^3$ In the massless case $m=0$ the single-cut amplitude becomes:

$$\begin{align}
i{\cal M}_1&(p^2\!=\!-(p^0)^2)\cr
~\stackrel{(J)}{=}~&{\rm Vol}(\mathbb{S}^{d-2})
\int_{\mathbb{R}_+}\!\frac{k^{d-3}dk}{2(2\pi)^{d-1}}
\frac{1}{2kp^0 -(p^0)^2-i\epsilon}\cr
~\stackrel{\text{GR3.192.4}}{=}&-\frac{{\rm Vol}(\mathbb{S}^{d-2})}{8(2\pi)^{d-2}p^0\sin(d\!-\!3)\pi}
\left(-\frac{p^0}{2}-\frac{i\epsilon}{2p^0}\right)^{d-3}
,\end{align}\tag{0}$$

where we have used

$$\begin{align}\int_{\mathbb{R}_+} \frac{x^{-c}~dx}{ax+b}
~=~&\frac{\pi}{a\sin c\pi}\left(\frac{b}{a}\right)^{-c}, 
\cr {\rm Re}\frac{b}{a}~\geq~0,&\qquad{\rm Im}\frac{b}{a}~\neq~0,\qquad c\in]0,1[. 
\end{align}\tag{GR3.192.4}$$

One may check that the 1-cut amplitude (O) is consistent with the monodromy (N).

The integrand (O) has a branch cut along the negative real $k$-axis. The denominator has a simple pole at

$$ k~=~\frac{p^0}{2}+\frac{i\epsilon}{2p^0}. \tag{P} $$

Comment: In point (J), since there is a square root of k, I expect to have a branch cut. 1. In point (P), there is no square root of k, so why is there a branch cut? 2. Why is the branch cut along the negative real k axis?

Comment: Hi @Andrea Pari. Thanks for the feedback. 1. Because $d$ is not necessarily an integer in dim. reg. 2. By convention.